# Enable Http PUT requests on .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, http-put

I'm working on an MVC application. On my original draft of the service I had this method in one of my controllers:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [ActionName("UpdateRelationship")]
    public ActionResult UpdateRelationship(string aParameter)
```

And that worked fine. In the latest revision I've been asked to change this into a PUT request to differentiate it from a similar add mechanism which uses post. So I changed it to this:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Put)]
    [ActionName("UpdateRelationship")]
    public ActionResult UpdateRelationship(string aParameter)
```

And suddenly I'm getting a 404 on my requests, all from just changing the AcceptVerbs. From the look of the error, it appears as though IIS is trying to route the request as a standard webforms page rather than using MVC extensionless url re-writing.

Googling this it seems that a common cause is browsers not allowing PUT requests but I'm not using a browser to test this - I'm using Fiddler. So there should be no problem there. I also think the correct settings are already in the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
        <remove name="MvcHttpHandler" />
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
        <add name="MvcHttpHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="*.mvc" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <verbs>
                <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
            </verbs>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

So what have I missed?

EDIT: This code works on a colleagues' machine. So it looks like my local setup of IIS as at fault. Still at a loss to explain what I need to change though - any ideas?

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: Are you using IIS Express or full-blooded IIS? If full-blooded, which OS are you on?

Comment: It's the one that comes built in to Windows 7 pro - so I assume that's express.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much fruitless searching and blind alleys involving WebDAV I found the answer on another SO family site :)

https://serverfault.com/questions/93424/how-to-enable-put-and-delete-in-iis7

Comment: What extension you updated?  The answer says to udpdae any extension (.aspx/.ascx), for MVC, there is no such extension. Can you elaborate your answer ?

Answer (score 10):

I had to remove the WebDav Module completely a stated in [this blog post](http://bradkingsley.com/putpostdelete-verb-errors-on-site/)

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This solved my issue on GoDaddy shared hosting. By default only GET and POST are enabled but this allowed PUT and DELETE (and HEAD) for my REST api.

Comment: Don´t forget to remove the module WebDAVModule like this post says, that is the reason it was not working in GoDaddy host.

Comment: After almost two days fighting this problem, you saved my life. Thanks man. This really solved my problem with GO_TRASH_DADDY.

Answer (score 3):

The configuration that worked for us was the following.

```
    <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

This is specific to extension-less URLs.

BTW the general recommendation is to set runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests = false.

Comment: Line is wrong, should be `<add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" preCondition="" />`