# Unable to call PUT method (MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Assuming I have User Model as :-

```
public class User{
  prop UserId
  prop Name
}
```

Now my Controller is :-

```
public class MyController: AsyncController
{
  [HttpPost]
  public void Add(User user)
  {

  }
  [HttpPut]
  public void UpdateUser(User user)
  {

  }

}
```

Now, I use fiddler and I can successfully post data to my `Add()` but not to PUT method.

> Error:- Method not allowed

I have wasted my day with this issue, searched `stackoverflow` and googled around, but couldn't get it working... I am not getting the solution.

`-ve votes` are highly appreciated with some comments. Please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161354/enable-http-put-requests-on-net-mvc

Comment: Why do you have both? You should be using one or the other. [A Good Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)

Comment: James:- I am using Backbone.js, so to follow the Rest flow I am doing it. As per my undertstanding POST=Create Record and PUT= Update record. I know using POST I can achieve both... Hope I am correct!

Answer (score 0):

If the web server that you are using is IIS puts are not enabled by default. See https://serverfault.com/questions/93424/how-to-enable-put-and-delete-in-iis7