# Kendo ui attach files to PUT request : javascript

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am Working with kendoui dataSource w.r.t to the schema. Its working fine and code is below,

```
   var dataSourceContactsLeft = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: function () {
                    //some urls
                },
                dataType: "json"
            },
            create: {
                url: function () {
                   //url
                },
                type: "POST"
            },
            update: {
                url: function () {
                    return crudServiceBaseUrl + "Test/PUT";
                },
                type: "PUT",
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        batch: false,
        //pageSize: 20,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "SomeId",
                fields: {
                    //fields
                }
            }
        },
        requestEnd: function (e) {
            //some code
        },
        change: function () {

        }
    });
```

I have a problem to solve, when PUTTING request, there are input files i also need to post. that can be

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
```

If there is any way i can do that or any best practice to upload the files with PUT request in kendo?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have looked into PUT issues?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161354/enable-http-put-requests-on-net-mvc